# What feats expand a character's critical range?

Tags: dnd-4e, critical-hit

What dnd 4e feats exist that expand a character's critical range?  For example, my cleric took the paragon path `Radiant Servant` and was granted the feat `Illuminating Attacks`, which makes his radiant attack a critical on 19 or 20.  I would like to know this to keep in mind for other characters that I may make in the future.

Comment: Be sure to check with your DM. There are some well known commentators that think expanding crit range is one of the ways 4e is broken. Particularly, how the "on crit" based powers, combined with these feats leads to "outrageous" chains of effects. See: http://slyflourish.com/dd_essential_conversations_with_kato_katonian.html

Comment: @F. Randall Farmer, this'll be our first foray into paragon tier.  if we decide that the expanded crit range is too powerful i'll change to something else.  but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a search on the compendium for "critical 19-20" under feats

- Power of Luck: 19-20 for Bond of Censure, Holy Strike, Lance of Faith, Vanguard's Lightning
- Ogremight Bruiser: Fighter, Ogremight Student, 19-20 on charging and 2h hammer (what's that, Mordenkrad and Avalanche hammer?)
- Ogremight Ravager: Warlord, Ogremight Student, as above.
- Steel vanguard captain: Warlord, 19-20 on certain encounter powers with 2h heavy blade
- Steel Vanguard Soldier, Fighter, as above
- Steel Vanguard Student, 19-20, 2h weapon, cleave and viper's strike
- Defiling Adept, 19-20 on daily arcane with defiling
- Phantasmal Destruction, 19-20 on wizard illusion powers with combat advantage. Note "Illusion Master" from mage, Illusion Master: When you hit or miss a target using an arcane illusion power, the target grants combat advantage for the next attack made against it before the end of your next turn.
- Violent Joy: 19-20 on... ardent edge case.  When you target a bloodied ally with your ardent surge and that ally regains enough hit points to no longer be bloodied, he or she can score critical hits with melee attacks on a roll of 19–20 until the end of your next turn.
- Advantageous Perspective: Small creature, When you make a melee weapon attack, you score a critical hit on a natural roll of 19 or 20 against Large or larger creatures granting combat advantage to you.
- Plunging Blade: Fighter, OA with light blade.

Epic Feats:

They fall into two categories: class based implement and stat based *melee* weapon. Most older classes have them. Some builds get royally screwed.

Implement Mastery:

- Bard
- Sorcerer
- Warlock
- Wizard
- Avenger(special)
- Swordmage
- Psion

Comment: +1. Interesting enough is the same search on DDI with "critical 18-20" ^_^

Answer (score 2):

To start there are the following feats:

- Weapon Mastery Feats give expanded crit range (19-20) to weapons by category (heavy blades, light blades etc). These have a stat prerequisite and are available in epic.

There are also some paragon paths that give expanded crit range for instance:

- Dagger Master (Rogue) expands crit range to 18-20 on dagger attacks.
- Radiant Servant (Cleric) expands crit range to 19-20 on radiant attacks.